# Файл жёлтого цветa PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, ide

Не изменяются файлы и не обнаруживаются в проекте. Почему такой цвет и как его убрать ??
[image: Не изменяются эти файлы]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что это были файлы, которые игнорировались в Version Control